# Easy and fast way to access UIView from different threads

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, ipad

I have an interface like this:

```
@interface AView : UIScrollView
{
    UIView* m_view1;
    UIView* m_view2;
    ...
}

-(void) method1;
-(void) method2;
...
@end
```

I need to access views from methods of the interface. I need to create, release, re-create them and also set properties.

The problem is, some methods of the interface are running in different threads. Since these methods access same views I have issues like one thread trying to re-create a view when another thread is trying to set some properties of a view being recreated.

How should I synchronize access to views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, do you know you can ONLY call the methods of the UIView class (and it's subclasses) in the main thread? But, if you are just doing **create** and **release** job in second thread, it's OK to do it.

> **Threading Considerations**
>
> Manipulations to your application’s user interface **must** occur on the
>   main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView
>   class from code running in the main thread of your application. The
>   only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view
>   object itself; but all other manipulations should occur on the main
>   thread.

In addition, you can use `@synchronized() {object}` to lock an object. But still, you can NOT call UIView's methods in second thread (in Objective-C even set property is calling method) even you've locked it.

> Objective-C supports multithreading in applications. Therefore, two
>   threads can try to modify the same object at the same time, a
>   situation that can cause serious problems in a program. To protect
>   sections of code from being executed by more than one thread at a
>   time, Objective-C provides the @synchronized() directive.
>
> The @synchronized()directive locks a section of code for use by a
>   single thread. Other threads are blocked until the thread exits the
>   protected code—that is, when execution continues past the last
>   statement in the @synchronized() block.
>
> The @synchronized() directive takes as its only argument any
>   Objective-C object, including self.

Comment: I was expecting something more than excerpt from documentation but probably was expecting too much. Anyway, this is most complete answer so I mark it as "the answer".

Answer (score 2):

You can use **NSLock** for example, but you shouldn't update your UI from other threads. The only thread from which you should update UI Is the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

UIKit can only be used safely on the main thread! Do you use `NSOperation`? 
You will see the usage of`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` to move operations done from other threads to the main thread.